# semantic content recommendation system with Amazon SageMaker, storing in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am fairly new to AWS and Sagemaker and have decided to follow some of the tutorials Amazon has to familiarize myself with it. I've been following this one ([tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/semantic-content-recommendation-system-amazon-sagemaker/5/)) and I've realized that it's an older tutorial using Sagemaker v1. I've been able to look up and change whatever is needed for the tutorial to work in v2 but I became stuck at this part for storing the training data in a S3 bucket to deploy the model.

```
import io
import sagemaker.amazon.common as smac

print('train_features shape = ', predictions.shape)
print('train_labels shape = ', labels.shape)
buf = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, predictions, labels)
buf.seek(0)

bucket = BUCKET
prefix = PREFIX
key = 'knn/train'
fname = os.path.join(prefix, key)
print(fname)
boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(fname).upload_fileobj(buf)
s3_train_data = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, key)
print('uploaded training data location: {}'.format(s3_train_data))
```

It returns this error

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-20-9e52dd949332> in <module>
 3
 4
----> 5 print('train_features shape = ', predictions.shape)
 6 print('train_labels shape = ', labels.shape)
 7 buf = io.BytesIO()
NameError: name 'predictions' is not defined
```

I'm curious as to why this would have worked in Sagemaker v1 and not v2 if predictions is not defined and if anyone could point me in the right direction for correcting this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they've left some of the code out, or changed the terminology and left in predictions by accident. predictions is an object that is defined on this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-test-model.html

You'll have to work out what predictions is in your case.